# Making a right triangle by arrays in python using loops and auto filling the arrays

Tags: python, arrays, loops, math

I want to write a program that can help me to calculate some values using python.
The main idea is I want to make a table, which is only half of the cells are having value. (That means I want to make a triangle) So, the triangle I want to make is like this format.

```
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

But, things are not that easy. Please see the table below. (Also same as [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URL9t.png))

```
6.00 6.45 6.80 7.10 7.36 7.56 7.77
6.90 7.20 7.47 7.70 7.88 8.06
7.50 7.75 7.97 8.12 8.30
8.00 8.20 8.33 8.50
8.40 8.50 8.67
8.60 8.80
9.00
```

In the above triangle, each of the rows is make from the previous row by a certain formula. Please refer to the [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaEz2.png) and [picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQWWI.png).

Also, please note that in the above triangle, each of the cells was multiplied by 100. For example, the 6.00 in the upper left corner is 6% (0.06) indeed. << Please do NOT multiplied the figures by 100 in my program, because it is just an accident here for demonstration.

Okay. So, I want to make a program that as long as I input the first row, then the program will calculate and show the remaining rows for me. (That means showing the whole triangle)

Below is my code. Please have a look. I have tried to write a frame, but there are two problems that I encounter.

1. I don't know how to automatically fill my other arrays(the other rows) base on the first arrays (the first row) that I input in the program.
2. I keep receiving the error of "IndexError: list index out of range" when I try to run my programme.

Here are my codes

```
array1 = [0.06,0.0645,0.068,0.071,0.0736,0.0756,0.0777]         #This is the initial array that I input
array2 = []            #This should be the output after the first iteration, I hope that my programme can auto fill the remaining arrays (including this array) after I run my programme
array3 = []            #This is a blank array waiting for auto fill after I run my program
array4 = []            #This is a blank array waiting for auto fill after I run my program
array5 = []            #This is a blank array waiting for auto fill after I run my program
array6 = []            #This is a blank array waiting for auto fill after I run my program
array7 = []            #This is a blank array waiting for auto fill after I run my program
array8 = []            #This is a blank array waiting for auto fill after I run my program


r = 0  # Set the initial position for the table that I want to make, and this is similar to the x-asis. Please refer to picture 2.
s = 1  # Set the initial position for the table that I want to make, and this is similar to the y-asis. Please refer to picture 2.



def SpotRateForcast(i,j,k):
    global r
    global s
    
    while (r <= len(k)):                                     # I try to make the first loop here
        s = 1                                                # Reset the value when the first row is completed such that the second loop can work in the second row
        while (s <= len(k)):                                 # this is the second loop to determine when to stop in the each row
            x = ((((1 + k[j - 1])**j) / ((1 + k[i - 1])**i))**(1/(j-i))) - 1  #Calculate the value by the certain formula
            print(("%.4f" % round(x,4)), end=' ,  ')         #Print the value up to 4 decimal places  
            s += 1                                           #Record one value is calculated and done
            SpotRateForcast(i,j+1,k)                         #Start to calculate and print the next value                         
        r += 1                                               # Switch to the next row when the second loop is finished
        
        
SpotRateForcast(r,s,array1)                                  #The code to run the program
```

Thank you for reading my question.
I would like to ask someone to finish the programme for me. As you can see, my coding maybe bad because I am a newbie in programming. But I already tried my best to do everything I am able to do.

I do not mind your edit my codes. It is even better if you can write a new codes for me. And I can learn how to write better codes from you.

Lastly, I have one more request. Please add many many comments in the codes you wrote otherwise I may not able to understand what you wrote(I am a beginner). Thank you very much!

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image of text.

Comment: No problem Sir. I had post my code as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overthinking it.

If you only need to print a triangle, just print each row in sequence, and for each row print its values in sequence:

```
S = [0.06,0.0645,0.068,0.071,0.0736,0.0756,0.0777]

n = len(S)

print(('{:0.4f} ' * n).format(*S))  # print initial line

for i in range(1,n):                # loop over rows
    for j in range(i+1, n+1):       # then over colums
        num = (1 + S[j -1])**j
        den = (1 + S[i - 1])**i
        x = (num/den)**(1/(j - i)) -1       # ok we have f(i, j)
        print('{:0.4f}'.format(x), end=' ') # print it followed with a space 
    print('')                       # add a newline after a full row
```

It gives:

```
0.0600 0.0645 0.0680 0.0710 0.0736 0.0756 0.0777 
0.0690 0.0720 0.0747 0.0770 0.0787 0.0807 
0.0750 0.0775 0.0797 0.0812 0.0830 
0.0801 0.0821 0.0833 0.0850 
0.0841 0.0849 0.0867 
0.0857 0.0880 
0.0904
```

Now if you want to first build arrays because you will later post-process them, just append each field value to a list for the row, and then append each of those lists to a global list of lists

```
S = [0.06,0.0645,0.068,0.071,0.0736,0.0756,0.0777]

n = len(S)

result = [S]                        # add the initial row

for i in range(1,n):                # loop over rows
    row = []                            # prepare a new list for the row
    result.append(row)                  # and append it to result
    for j in range(i+1, n+1):       # then over colums
        num = (1 + S[j -1])**j
        den = (1 + S[i - 1])**i
        x = (num/den)**(1/(j - i)) -1       # ok we have f(i, j)
        row.append(x)               # as a list is modifiable we can append to it
```

Comment: Thank you Bro. You help me a lot  !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
array=[[0.06,0.0645,0.068,0.071,0.0736,0.0756,0.0777]]

n = len(array[0])

#outer loop

for i in range(1, n):

       #append new row

    array.append([])
    
    for j in range(n-i):
        #i dont understand your calculations but they'd stand
        array[i][j] = #here
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).